# Positioning div inside another div

Tags: html, css

I am creating login form for my website but the layout should match to standard image. I'm developing a copy for that image. I have a div (`position: absolute`) which is main panel and I have some div tags inside of it. I want to position the "Keep me logged in" text correctly according to the following image. That text should be vertically aligned middle to the checkbox. This is my layout:

http://jsfiddle.net/nisa_sala/uA99f/

*This is my target layout:*

[image: text is vertically middle of the checkbox]

*This is my failed layout:*

[image: this is my failed layout // vertically bottom relative to checkbox]

**HTML**

```
<div id="apDiv27">
    <div class="bot_con" id="bc1"><label id="lab_1">Email or Phone:</label>
      <input type="text" name="textfield4" id="textfield4" />
</div>
    <div class="bot_con" id="bc2"><label id="lab_2">Password:</label>
      <input type="text" name="textfield5" id="textfield5" />
    </div>
    <div class="bot_con" id="bc3">

        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" id="checkbox2" />
      <label id="lab_3">Keep me logged in  </label>
    </div>
    <div class="bot_con" id="bc4"><a href="http://people-analize.herokuapp.com" target="_blank" tabindex="-1">Forgot your password?</a></div>
  </div>
```

I uploaded my 2 images. How can I position this text vertically middle relative to check box ?

Answer (score 0):

> ... that text should be vertically middle relative to checkbox ...

`vertical-align: middle` is what you are looking for.

Updated fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/uA99f/1/**

CSS:

```
input, label {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: but it's up not middle

Comment: it is perfectly middle in the fiddle. checked it on chrome and firefox both!

Answer (score 0):

add `label{ vertical-align: middle}` and change `line-height: 1.28;` on `#apDiv27 #bc3` to `line-height: 1.9;`